# Chaining dynamic prereqs in Makefile

Tags: makefile, prerequisites

I'm trying to figure out a Makefile problem I've got.  I start with a lot of files in a `telemetry/` directory, and for each one I need to create a corresponding file in a `features/` directory.

The list of filenames in the `telemetry/` directory is cached in a `filelist` file, and I define an `allfeats` target to encompass all the file-level targets.  Except the `allfeats` target doesn't actually work.

My Makefile (heavily trimmed to just show this issue) looks like this:

```
MYSAMP:=$(shell cat filelist)

allfeats: $(patsubst %,features/%-feat.rds,$(MYSAMP))
        @echo done

features/%-feat.rds: telemetry/%
        Rscript -e 'saveRDS(process("$<"), "$@")'

print-%:
        @echo $* = $($*)
```

But something about the timing of variable propagation, I think, isn't letting me chain rules the way I intend:

```
% make -n allfeats
make: *** No rule to make target `features/709731-feat.rds', needed by `allfeats'.  Stop.
```

It does actually know how to create that target if I specify it explicitly:

```
% make -n features/709731-feat.rds
Rscript -e 'saveRDS(process("telemetry/709731"), "features/709731-feat.rds")'
```

Is there a different way to define my rules (or variables) that will work as intended?

Comment: I can also work around it by inserting the file list into the Makefile as a literal, rather than reading from `filelist`.  But I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I had generated the `filelist` file by doing this:

```
% ls telemetry > filelist
```

But I forgot that my `ls` is aliased like so:

```
% which ls
ls='ls -FG --color --hide="NTUSER.DAT*"'
```

So I had the coloration escape sequences in the file too, which were invisible to the naked eye, but reveal themselves in an octal dump:

```
% head filelist | od -a
0000000 esc   [   0   m esc   [   0   m   7   0   9   7   3   1 esc   [
0000020   0   m  nl esc   [   0   m   8   0   0   3   3   3 esc   [   0
0000040   m  nl esc   [   0   m   8   0   0   3   3   4 esc   [   0   m
0000060  nl esc   [   0   m   8   0   0   3   3   5 esc   [   0   m  nl
0000100 esc   [   0   m   8   0   0   8   3   2 esc   [   0   m  nl esc
0000120   [   0   m   8   0   0   8   3   3 esc   [   0   m  nl esc   [
0000140   0   m   8   0   0   8   3   4 esc   [   0   m  nl esc   [   0
0000160   m   8   0   0   8   3   6 esc   [   0   m  nl esc   [   0   m
0000200   8   0   0   8   4   8 esc   [   0   m  nl esc   [   0   m   8
0000220   0   2   0   3   1 esc   [   0   m  nl
```

Once I cleaned those out, the Makefile chaining works as expected.